# How do I display a stored procedure outcome to a textfield on a DevExpress web dashboard?

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-blazor

I have a stored procedure that simply returns the current date formatted as below.

`SELECT 'Last Updated: ' + convert(VARCHAR, GETUTCDATE(), 113) AS CurrentTime`

As DevExpress don't allow you to specifically display a datetime field on their dashboards I thought I would be able to do a work around and bind the result of this SP to a textbox. The issue is, you can't bind SP results to be displayed within textboxes using their dashboard editor. Is there any possible way to do this? I can't add fields external to the dashboard and it doesn't look like we're going to be moving away from implementing their software into ours.